# How to force Slack to reconnect?

Tags: macos, slack

I use the standalone Slack client for macOS. When I switch or join a wi-fi network, I often get this message:

[image: Trouble connecting to slack]

It doesn't go away, even after my connection is working. I haven't found a way to tell the client to try reconnecting, other than quitting and restarting.

Is there a better way to tell Slack to attempt to reconnect?

Comment: This seems to be working better in recent updates. Every once in a while, I need to quit the entire client and let it reconnect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can actually force the client to refresh now with `command + R` (`ctrl + R` for Windows). This will force the entire client to refresh and reconnect if you're having connection issues, provided that it's not on your end. You should also now see an option to see a status page for Slack if your connection is down to verify that it's you or them.

Comment: I think you meant `command + R`. It worked for me.

Comment: @PhilDulac You're right! I wrote this when I solved the issue myself on Windows, brain fart. Thank you for the correction.